# How can Bookmark look up be ignored?

Tags: performance, indexing, sql-server-2000

Bookmark look up is taking long time when executing a SQL 2000 query. How can this issue be solved using Query hint or Index?

Comment: By creating a covering index.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend getting a proper understanding of this situation and how to address it. So instead of giving a cut down overview, it would be more beneficial for you to have a read through [this MSDN article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217123527/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/craigfr/archive/2006/06/30/652639.aspx).

That explains exactly what it means, shows some samples and how to address it. Well worth a read.